# How to store user created through signup page to Google Cloud MySQL database through Python3 Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Can anyone provide me a link or guidance on how to proceed to store the users created through signup page using django's auth libs to Google Cloud SQL? I am unable to store the data as well as retrieve it in order for the person to login into the website.

`from django.shortcuts import render

```
# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import Context, loader
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import auth


def home(request):
    template = loader.get_template("home.html")
    return HttpResponse(template.render())


def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            login(request, user)
            template = loader.get_template("login.html")
            return HttpResponse(template.render())

        else:
            for msg in form.error_messages:
                print(form.error_messages[msg])
            return render(request=request,
                          template_name="signup.html",
                          context={"form": form})

       form = UserCreationForm
       return render(request=request,
                  template_name="signup.html",
                  context={"form": form})


def login(request):
    template = loader.get_template("login.html")
    return HttpResponse(template.render())


def login_view(request):
    username = request.POST['uname']
    password = request.POST['psw']
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        #correct password, and the user is marked "active"
        auth.login(request, user)
        #redirect to the success page
        template = loader.get_template("index.html")
        return HttpResponse(template.render())
    else:
        #show an error page
        return HttpResponseRedirect() #add error page link


def logout_view(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    #redirect to a success page
    return HttpResponseRedirect() #add page link`
```

Answer (score 2):

To connect your Cloud SQL database to your Django's App, a Python 3 database connector library compatible with Django is needed.

We will need to install the database connector, ***mysqlclient***, which is a forked version of MySQLdb.

According to the mysqlclient documentation, “MySQLdb is a thread-compatible interface to the popular MySQL database server that provides the Python database API.” The main difference being that mysqlclient has the added benefit of including Python 3 support.

Follow the steps:

1) You will need to install the following libraries, add these into your requirements.txt file :
   python3-dev
   libmysqlclient-dev
   mysqlclient
   mysql-server

With this, we will install MySQL server and the MySQL client using the PyPi mysqlclient connector library.

2) Add the MySQL Database Connection to your Application

- ***settings.py***

```
..
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': '/etc/mysql/my.cnf',
        },
    }
}
...
```

- Edit your config.py file to add your MySQL credentials.

***my.cnf***

```
...
[client]
database = db_name
user = db_user
password = db_password
default-character-set = utf8
```

3) Sigup fucntion:

```
def signup(request):
    registered = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            registered = True
            login(request, user)
            template = loader.get_template("login.html")
            return HttpResponse(template.render())
        else:
            for msg in form.error_messages:
                print(form.error_messages[msg])
            return render(request=request,
                          template_name="signup.html",
                          context={"form": form})
    else:
        user_form = UserCreationForm()

        return render(request=request,
                  template_name="signup.html",
                  context={"form": form})
```

4) Login function:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
                template = loader.get_template("index.html")
                return HttpResponse(template.render())
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Your account was inactive.")
        else:
            print("Someone tried to login and failed.")
            print("They used username: {} and password: {}".format(username,password))
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details given")
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect() #add error page link
```

Comment: I have already done this. Moreover, I believe don't I have to create a table to store these created users? And my google cloud SQL instance is not getting connected to the web application as I am seeing 500 gateway error when I try to do signup. In addition, I am not seeing my table or data stored in cloud MySQLdb.

Comment: I supposed you created the Models to be stored in SQL. [Here](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_models/) is a tutorial  where it explains how to create models in Django. Could you please share the error you are seeing in the Google Cloud Platform Logging for your SQL instance?